# __get() function behavior in php

Tags: php, getter-setter

I was trying to find the sequence in which magical methods are called in PHP. Hence wrote a very basic program

```
class testme
{
    public $var1;
    /*function __construct()
    {
        echo'<br/> Constructor called';
    }*/
      public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        echo'<br/> You are in sssset function';
    }
    public function __call($method,$arg)
    {
        echo '<br/> call method';
    }
    public function __get($name)
    {
        echo'<br/> You are in get function';
    }
    public function __isset($name)
    {
        echo'<br/> You are in isset function';
    }
    public function __unset($name)
    {
        echo'<br/> You are in unset function';
    }   
       function __destruct() {
       print "<br/>Destroying " . $this->name . "\n";
   }
}
$obj = new testme;
$obj->var1=5;
```

The expected output was

```
You are in set function
Destroying
```

Getting:

```
You are in get function
Destroying
```

`$obj->var1=5` Here I am setting the value to the class var then why it is calling `__get`. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do a `var_dump` on `$name` inside of `__get`, you'll see it contains `name`. The `__get` function is actually being called in `__destruct`. This is because `$var1` is an accessible member, therefore, does not call the `__get` or `__set` functions.

From the [PHP Documentation:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)

> **The overloading methods are invoked
>   when interacting with properties or
>   methods that have not been declared or
>   are not visible in the current scope**.
>   The rest of this section will use the
>   terms "inaccessible properties" and
>   "inaccessible methods" to refer to
>   this combination of declaration and
>   visibility.

Since `$var1` is defined and public, there is no call to the magic methods.

Answer (score 5):

**You have a `$var1` property in your class, so `__set` is not called** : it's only called when there is no property with the name of the one you're trying to set.

Remove that public `$var1` property, and `__set` will be called.

Still, even after removing that property, `__get` is still called.

If you put an echo at the end of your script, you'll see that __get is called after than echo -- i.e. after what seems to be the end of your script.

And if you take a look at your destructor method :

```
function __destruct() {
    print "<br/>Destroying " . $this->name . "\n";
}
```

You see that **this destructor tries to read from a non-existant property -- hence the call to `__get`**.

Comment: Thanks Pascal. one more question I have.I did $obj->temp=5; I modified my $obj->var1 to $obj->temp and it gives expected result as I was expecting previously.Then I tried printing this new variable echo '<br/>inaccessible property: '.$obj->temp.'<br/>';but, it is not printing the value 5. Can you help me to understand this?.

Comment: If your __set method is not storing the value somewhere, and the __get method is not returning the value from somewhere... it won't print much ;-) *(when using those methods, you are the one responsible for storing/reading the value)*

Answer (score 0):

`__get`/`__set` are only called if a public variable is not available.  Try `$obj->var2=5` and you'll get the expected result.

`__get` is being called because your destruct command includes an unknown parameter `$this->name`

Answer (score 0):

`get` is being called by the destructor (`$this->name`).  The class has no `name` member, so magical get is called.  Magical `set` is only called if you try to set a member that does not exist.  `var1` exists, so `__set()` does not need to be called.

You state

> I was trying to find the sequence in
>   which magical methods are called

Magical methods are all called by mutually exclusive constructs, so there is never any way to call more than one with the same operation.  They aren't called in a sequence.